# How to make a tag with dynamic content full height inside of td tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table where I load dynamic content, and I want that the content inside the cells is the same height as the cells! Precisely I have "a" elements with some text, inside the td cells. I get a problem when the text in a cell is long and goes at newline, and like you can see in the image the other "a" elements in the table row don't fit the full height of the cell.

See the live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wg6paumw/3/)

[image: table]

Here is the code

HTML

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Titolo</th>
        <th>Sede</th>
        <th>Città</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">12/02/2015</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17"><span class="fixed glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>asd</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">ada</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">asdas</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">04/02/2015</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13"><span class="fixed glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>ada</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">prova</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">asda</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">07/09/2017</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Evento Lignano <br>
  sabbiadoro</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Palazzetto dello Sport</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Perugia</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">09/09/2015</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">09/03/2015</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">sfsd</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">ada</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">dadasd</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
table{
    width:400px;
}
td a{
    background:#ff0;
    display: block;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

td{
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
}
td a {
  background: #ff0;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Titolo</th>
      <th>Sede</th>
      <th>Città</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">12/02/2015</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17"><span class="fixed glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>asd</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">ada</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=17">asdas</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">04/02/2015</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13"><span class="fixed glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>ada</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">prova</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=13">asda</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">07/09/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Evento Lignano <br>
  sabbiadoro</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Palazzetto dello Sport</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=12">Perugia</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">09/09/2015</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=54">aaa</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">09/03/2015</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">sfsd</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">ada</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="eventi.php?id=25">dadasd</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little hack I've used in the past.

You can essentially add a pseudo element to the `a` element and absolutely position it *relative* to the closest `td` element. Since the pseudo elements are essentially children elements of the `a` element, when you click the pseudo element, you are inadvertently clicking the `a` element.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/v7y3yu3v/)

```
td a:after, td a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
td a:after {
  background: #ff0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But like that if I have to add some border to the "a" element I would still have the same problem! I could add the border to the "td" element, but for information, is there no concrete solution to this problem?

Comment: @Manuel Couldn't you add the border to the pseudo element? https://jsfiddle.net/akckumxt/

Answer (score 0):

You must define an height of your TD, otherwise the browser doesn't know the 100% of what is to be considered:

```
td {
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wg6paumw/4/

Comment: It is dynammic content, so i can't just set a fixed height

Comment: yes, but he says he wants the content being "same height" of the cell: putting the background of the cells to yellow doesn't solve the problem either; he can't know in advance the height of a cell without defining it, at least not with CSS only